# Why can I only use sum on this formula monitor?

Tags: datadog

I'm trying to create a monitor that alerts when error rate is beyond a threshold using the below setup. Both of the metrics used in the formula are `count` metrics. Why does datadog only allow using `sum`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the usage of `as_count()`.

I found the following in [Datadog's documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/guide/as-count-in-monitor-evaluations/):

> In general, avg time aggregation with .as_rate() is reasonable, but sum aggregation with .as_count() is recommended for error rates. Aggregation methods other than sum do not make sense to use with (and cannot be used with) .as_count().